# Ignoring a group based on a condition from final output

Tags: sql-server

I have the following query:

```
SELECT
  MachineName, 
  OperationId, 
  UserId,
  RecordStamp,
  Thread, 
  [Level], 
  Logger, 
  Message, 
  Exception
FROM
  dbo.MainLog
GROUP BY
  MachineName, 
  OperationId, 
  UserId,
  RecordStamp,
  Thread, 
  [Level], 
  Logger, 
  Message, 
  Exception
ORDER BY 
  RecordStamp DESC;
```

This is the output:

[image: SQL Output]

Now, the first group has only `INFO` levels. I want to ignore this group. Next group has a `WARN` and I need to include all of this group. How do I filter out groups with only `INFO` type events? I tried to setup a HAVING clause but with in HAVING, I can still only filter rows and got group of rows. **I do not want to filter everything with `INFO` Level. I want to *not* include all groups having only `INFO` events.**

Comment: the LEVEL have only two values: INFO and WARN?
Yo what i understand you want all OPERATION_ID that had at least a WARN, right?

Comment: please specify by what you want to group ... select A,B,C ... group by A,B,C is a degenerated case ... group by will give you one row per group ...so when you say you don't want to filter rows but groups that means your grouping is a mess

Comment: And what happens when a "group" has both an INFO and a WARN? Or any other level value? Are you making assumptions? Know your data! Using GROUP by clause without an aggregate is logically the same as using DISTINCT - and neither appears to do anything useful in your query.

Comment: @SMor that is the case that I want to include because that indicate something out of the ordinary happened as shown in the screen-shot. I'm not making assumptions. I know all the levels there are. As per the screenshot, I'm not interested in the Red groups only. Everything else is allowed and it is just the Level column targeted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
SELECT  MachineName,OperationId, UserId, RecordStamp,Thread,[Level],Logger, 
Message,Exception
FROM dbo.MainLog
WHERE OperationId IN (SELECT OperationId from dbo.MainLog WHERE LEVEL <> 'INFO'
GROUP BY OperationId)
```

Comment: This query is what I was looking for.